# find specific objects in managedObjectContext and calculate sum

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to wrap my head around CoreData. So I am having a static tableview for statistics with labels like: "number of entries", "total distance", "total time" etc. I have my coredata entity called "Recording" and its attributes "startDate","duration",... and I would like to fetch all entries from the CURRENT week and then on one hand display the number of entries and on the other hand the total time. I know how to set up a fetch request (thank you, google)

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    if (self.managedObjectContext)
    {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Recording" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                              managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                                sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                         cacheName:nil];
    frc.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = frc;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

but I am stuck with this special idea and I am not even sure if I need to do it with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it now using:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

NSEntityDescription *theType = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Recording" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
fetchRequest.entity = theType;

NSDate *firstDayOfCurrentWeek = [self firstWeekday:[NSDate date]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((startDate > %@) AND (startDate <= %@))",firstDayOfCurrentWeek, [NSDate date]];
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

NSSortDescriptor *theDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:theDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

and finding the sum/total like this:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResults = self.fetchedResultsController;

NSInteger allWorkouts = [[fetchedResults fetchedObjects] count];

CGFloat totalDistance = [[[fetchedResults fetchedObjects] valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.distance"] floatValue];
```

Thanks for the hint with the predicate :)

Answer (score 0):

`NSPredicate` is what you're searching for.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really get how to do this with dates..?

Comment: Do you have many records? I get all records and then check if every record date is inside an date interval

Comment: since the user will add records it could some up to a few hundred.. so I'd like to do it in an elegant way

Comment: I'll check tonight and tell you how i did